# Cohen's d and Sten scores

Tags: standard-error, standardization, cohens-d

Can someone explain why Cohen's d of sten score is 2 times of Cohen's d of SD? Thanks.

The question is based on the paragraph below:

*When looking at differences it is useful to remind ourselves of the scale of the differences and the impact, if any, there should be on profile interpretation.

In the following graphs and supporting text, Cohen’s d is referred to, where .20 of an SD (.40 of a Sten) is a small effect, .50 of an SD (1 Sten) is a medium or moderate effect size and .80 of an SD (1.60 Stens) is a large effect size.*